# C++: Moving elements off of STL container into a variable in a single statement?

Tags: c++, stl

Consider the following sequence of statements using std::list

```
//class C;

C c_obj;
std::list<C> my_list;

//...

std::swap(c_obj, my_list.front());
my_list.pop_front();
```

I would like to simply move the contents of my_list.front() to c_obj while removing the element from the list in a single statement (thus minimizing the number of statements and of copying). Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: And in case if there is an exception in between copying and removing?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is a way to get `front()` and `pop_front()` in the same expression. At least not in the `std::list` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that returns the popped value and use [`std::exchange()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange):

```
C& pop_front(std::list<C>& cont) {
    C& c(cont.front());
    cont.pop_front();
    return c;
}

int main() {
    C c_obj;
    std::list<C> my_list;
    my_list.emplace_front();

    std::exchange(c_obj, pop_front(my_list));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning std::exchange. I didn't know about it. Your method seems all right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is anything built in that will do this for you. You can write your own function to copy and then pop. If you know you're unlikely to be using that function for many other uses, you can make it a lambda expression so that it really is just one statement, disguised as an anonymous function call.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Alternatively, you could create a new list and then use splice to transfer the elements one at a time, making sure that nothing goes out of scope, then just dealing with the iterator to the element in the new list.